# Where must i throw an exception to prevent endless waiting in Task

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a hardware device connected to my PC over serial port, when i signal something to it, it signals back that "Hi, here I am!" and then it is successfully detected the port on which it is connected. I wrote a Task in C# that waits for the response coming from the hardware device, but if it is not connected, then this task is waiting forever.. Where can i throw an exception to prevent this endless waiting?

My code:

```
public static Task<string> GetDevicePortName()
{
    // Get all available serial ports on system.
    var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    var serialPort = new SerialPort();

    serialPort.BaudRate = Constants.DeviceConstants.BaudRate;
    serialPort.Parity = Constants.DeviceConstants.SerialPortParity;
    serialPort.StopBits = Constants.DeviceConstants.SerialPortStopBits;
    serialPort.WriteTimeout = Constants.DeviceConstants.WriteTimeoutInMilliseconds;

    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    serialPort.DataReceived += (s, e) => 
    {
        var dataIn = (byte)serialPort.ReadByte();
        var receivedCharacter = Convert.ToChar(dataIn);

        if (receivedCharacter == Constants.DeviceConstants.SignalYes)
        {
            serialPort.Dispose();
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(serialPort.PortName);
        }
    };

    foreach (var port in ports)
    {
        serialPort.PortName = port;

        try
        {
            serialPort.Open();
            serialPort.Write(Constants.DeviceConstants.SignalDeviceDetect);
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Comment: Something that might be useful to your project if it communicates "a lot" with the `SerialPort` would be to write a small helper class on top of `Ports.SerialPort` with a few simple methods like `Open(config) Close(dispose) string Read() Write(msg)` that are thread safe. You can then spawn `Task` to do you bidding in the way described in this answer possibly making the code a little cleaner.

Comment: This is great idea, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a "Custom timeout" combining `Task.WhenAny` with `Task.Delay`:

```
public async Task GetDevicePortNameAsync()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var timeOutTask = Task.Delay(5000, cts.Token);
    var deviceNameTask = GetDevicePortName(cts.Token);

    var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(timeOut, deviceNameTask);
    if (finishedTask == timeOutTask)
    {
        // You've timed-out
    }
    // If you get here, the deviceName is available.
}
```

Note this *won't* cancel the underlying registration to `SerialPort`.

**Edit**:

@KDecker adds an idea to pass a `CancellationToken` which can be monitored in case we've already timed out before returning the `TaskCompletionSource.Task`. It would look like this:

```
public static Task<string> GetDevicePortName(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Get all available serial ports on system.
    var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    var serialPort = new SerialPort();

    serialPort.BaudRate = Constants.DeviceConstants.BaudRate;
    serialPort.Parity = Constants.DeviceConstants.SerialPortParity;
    serialPort.StopBits = Constants.DeviceConstants.SerialPortStopBits;
    serialPort.WriteTimeout = Constants.DeviceConstants.WriteTimeoutInMilliseconds;

    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    serialPort.DataReceived += (s, e) => 
    {
        var dataIn = (byte)serialPort.ReadByte();
        var receivedCharacter = Convert.ToChar(dataIn);

        if (receivedCharacter == Constants.DeviceConstants.SignalYes)
        {
            serialPort.Dispose();
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(serialPort.PortName);
        }
    };

    foreach (var port in ports)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Unregister from serialPort, and clean up whatever needs to be cleaned
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            break;
        }

        serialPort.PortName = port;

        try
        {
            serialPort.Open();
            serialPort.Write(Constants.DeviceConstants.SignalDeviceDetect);
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
        finally
        {
            serialPort.Dispose();
        }
    }

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Comment: This works well. For completion make use of `TaskCancellationSource` and check a `CancellationToken` from that source throughout the serial port code. If you timeout you can then call cancel on the token and stop the serial port code from continuing, you can also cancel the `Task.Delay` if the serial port code finishes before it.

Comment: @KDecker That's a great comment. Added a possible implementation to the implementation.

Comment: Thank for the answer! :)